# How to check from a class library if a WPF Window is open

Tags: c#, wpf

I am opening a WPF window from a class library. How do I check from the class library if the WPF window is already opened? Any references to `System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows` produce this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Note: I created the class library from a WPF project which I changed the output type to Class Library.

Comment: Is the window in the same process? If you only ever want to show one instance of the window, have you considered making it a singleton?

Comment: I have not look into singleton and will do so. Thanks for the suggestion. I have also change my design such that I do not need to use a WPF window but instead a WinForm. I don't have any trouble checking instances of winform.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to references to **System.Windows** but unable to do so.

But enforcing a rule that only one instance of process is running is an interesting task. There are many other ways to code the algorithm on Win32. It would detect if there is an instance of your application already running. If detected, it will bring that application to the foreground (if it is minimized).

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class OnlyOneWindow
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] private static extern 
        bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] private static extern 
        bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] private static extern 
        bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
    private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
    private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
    private const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
    private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
    private const int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;

    public OnlyOneWindow()
    {
        // get the name of our process
        string proc=Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
        // get the list of all processes by that name
        Process[] processes=Process.GetProcessesByName(proc);
        // if there is more than one process...
        if (processes.Length > 1)
        {
            // Assume there is our process, which we will terminate, 
            // and the other process, which we want to bring to the 
            // foreground. This assumes there are only two processes 
            // in the processes array, and we need to find out which 
            // one is NOT us.

            // get our process
            Process p=Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            int n=0;        // assume the other process is at index 0
            // if this process id is OUR process ID...
            if (processes[0].Id==p.Id)
            {
                // then the other process is at index 1
                n=1;
            }
            // get the window handle
            IntPtr hWnd=processes[n].MainWindowHandle;
            // if iconic, we need to restore the window
            if (IsIconic(hWnd))
            {
                ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
            }
            // bring it to the foreground
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
            // exit our process
            return;
        }
        // ... continue with your application initialization here.
    }
}
```